# Emacs crashes with Segmentation Fault on WSL2, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The Emacs used to run safely yesterday cannot be launched with Segmentation Fault after upgraring Ubuntu.

Environment:

- Windows 10
- WSL2
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Emacs 28.1 (build 1.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-05-31

`emacs -Q` cannot be launched with the same error.
`emacs -nw` can be launched.
`xeyes` can be launched so I think X Window works fine.

Please give me any suggestion.

I attach the log of the Segment Fault below:

```
$ emacs& [1] 566 ~ $ Backtrace: emacs[0x530a92] emacs[0x4269f7]
emacs[0x426ee1] emacs[0x52efed] emacs[0x52f06d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520)[0x7f2118225520]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x1471253)[0x7f21014c9253]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x1470e54)[0x7f21014c8e54]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x14c11c5)[0x7f21015191c5]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2aa8719)[0x7f2102b00719]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2aa5bd5)[0x7f2102afdbd5]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2aa653a)[0x7f2102afe53a]
/usr/lib/wsl/drivers/nv_dispig.inf_amd64_7e5fd280efaa5445/libnvwgf2umx.so(+0x2c445d4)[0x7f2102c9c5d4]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x2dbab3)[0x7f2110df3ab3]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x2fee0c)[0x7f2110e16e0c]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x24c73f)[0x7f2110d6473f]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0xc47c9)[0x7f21111617c9]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x492ca)[0x7f21110e62ca]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x4919c)[0x7f21110e619c]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x4910f)[0x7f21110e610f]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x482a9)[0x7f21110e52a9]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x242fb2)[0x7f2110d5afb2]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x244533)[0x7f2110d5c533]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libD3D12Core.so(+0x244d3b)[0x7f2110d5cd3b]
/usr/lib/wsl/lib/libd3d12.so(+0x4851c)[0x7f21110e551c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb4cb56)[0x7f2111d7cb56]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb4b10c)[0x7f2111d7b10c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb4b3ba)[0x7f2111d7b3ba]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xacdf0)[0x7f21112dcdf0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0x6edf6b)[0x7f211191df6b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0x6edea7)[0x7f211191dea7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xad703)[0x7f21112dd703]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so(+0xb6749)[0x7f21112e6749]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0(+0x30243)[0x7f2113193243]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0(+0x36380)[0x7f2113199380]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0(+0x32eb5)[0x7f2113195eb5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0(epoxy_glx_version+0x2f)[0x7f2117f3945f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x74840)[0x7f211c1b0840]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x7beb9)[0x7f211c1b7eb9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x69aab)[0x7f211c1a5aab]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(gdk_display_manager_open_display+0x14f)[0x7f211c17468f]
... ^C [1]+  Segmentation fault      emacs ~
```

Comment: Keep in mind that questions on Stack Overflow should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. "unique to software development")*. For information on how to determine if a WSL question is programming-related (and where to post if it isn't), please see the [WSL tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/info).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded the WSL and the problem has been gone.

1. Launch cmd.exe
2. invoke `wsl --update`

That's all.